# npm not really uninstalling global package

Tags: nodejs, npm

This is a follow up question from something I posted on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181290/ionic-cli-not-uninstalling). Nobody was able to figure it out, and I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu system issue or not so forgive me if I'm in the wrong place but I wasn't sure where else to go with this.

I am trying to update my version of Ionic CLI but no matter what I try it seems to be stuck on version 2.1.1, it should be 3.10.1.

I tried uninstalling ionic with `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic` and it succeeds without a hitch. But for some reason I can still use the `ionic -v` command which still outputs 2.1.1. This command shouldn't work at all after uninstalling it.

I tried updating it anyway using `sudo npm install -g ionic@latest` and that also works without errors. But `ionic -v` still outputs 2.1.1, when it should be 3.10.1.

I also tried reinstalling nodejs and npm entirely and I still get the same thing.

I am on nodejs 8.5, npm 5.4.1, and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What does `which ionic` says?

Comment: @Hi-Angel it gives me `/usr/local/bin/ionic`

Comment: And what does `dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/ionic` says?

Comment: @Hi-Angel `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/ionic`

Comment: This is indeed weird. I've read a bit through man of npm, and did a quick *(local though)* installation and uninstallation of ionic, and it works fine. You most probably have encountered some bug of ionic. If your ultimate goal is to upgrade it to the newer version, I can only recommend to dive into technical details of where and how does npm stores its list of packages, to try to see e.g. whether it being removed from the list or not, what it does upon upgrading, et cetera… Running under `strace` might also give some insight.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

To resolve this:

1. Run `npm uninstall -g ionic`
2. Go to the location `/usr/local/bin/`
3. Delete the Ionic file
4. Close the terminal and open a new one, or start a new shell
5. Run `npm uninstall -g ionic`
6. Now run `ionic -v`

Comment: Thanks! This worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`chown -R "$(whoami)": "$(npm root -g)"`

You may need to use `sudo` for this operation.

And then uninstall using `sudo npm uninstall -g <package>`.
[Reference](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1219)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried all of the above including global uninstall and force clearing the cache.
What worked for me was:

```
> which create-react-app
> /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
> rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
> npm cache clean --force 
> npm cache verify
```

After that I was able to run `npx create-react-app myapp` and everything worked.
(Note that I am using OSX and not Ubuntu but wanted to post here anyway since I think the above would apply here as well.)

Comment: OSX is off topic here. Please post answers tested on Ubuntu and official derivatives.